How to pull the Primary key information from a table missing dates from a give date range in Oracle
I am new to SQL and trying to work on SQL that can help in pulling the records from a table that has missing date range. Below are the details.
CREATE TABLE a
(
    job_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    DATE   DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO a 
VALUES (1, '2024-01-01'),
       (1, '2024-02-01'),
       (1, '20 24-03-01'),
       (1, '2024-05-01'),
       (1, '2024-06-01'),
       (1, '2024-07-01'),
       (1, '2024-09-01'),
       (2, '2024-01-01'),
       (2, '2024-02-01'),
       (2, '2024-03-01'),
       (2, '2024-04-01'),
       (2, '2024-06-01')

The date range I provided is 01-JAN-2024 - 10-JAN-2024 and the result I am expecting is:
JOB_ID | DATE
-------+-------------
 1     |  2024-04-01
 1     |  2024-08-01
 1     |  2024-10-01
 2     |  2024-05-01
 2     |  2024-07-01
 2     |  2024-08-01
 2     |  2024-09-01
 2     |  2024-10-01


I think you are very confused about the date format. You are also trying to make duplicate primary keys..Can you try to work out a better example data set?

Create the table with a composite primary key (other wise you can only insert a single row for each job_id):
CREATE TABLE a (
  job_id   INT NOT NULL,
  dt       DATE NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT a__ji_d__pk PRIMARY KEY (job_id, dt)
);

Then insert the dates using a date literal (not a string literal):
INSERT INTO a (job_id, dt) VALUES
(1, DATE '2024-01-01'),
(1, DATE '2024-02-01'),
(1, DATE '2024-03-01'),
(1, DATE '2024-05-01'),
(1, DATE '2024-06-01'),
(1, DATE '2024-07-01'),
(1, DATE '2024-09-01'),
(2, DATE '2024-01-01'),
(2, DATE '2024-02-01'),
(2, DATE '2024-03-01'),
(2, DATE '2024-04-01'),
(2, DATE '2024-06-01');

Note: This syntax works from Oracle 23.
Then, to find the missing dates, use a row-generator to create a calendar and then use a PARTITIONed OUTER JOIN to find the missing values:
WITH calendar (day) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2024-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10
)
SELECT a.job_id,
       c.day
FROM   calendar c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN a
       PARTITION BY (a.job_id)
       ON (c.day = a.dt)
WHERE  a.dt IS NULL;

Which outputs:



JOB_ID
DAY




1
2024-04-01 00:00:00


1
2024-08-01 00:00:00


1
2024-10-01 00:00:00


2
2024-05-01 00:00:00


2
2024-07-01 00:00:00


2
2024-08-01 00:00:00


2
2024-09-01 00:00:00


2
2024-10-01 00:00:00



fiddle
